# How to add a new column from a stored proc to an existing SSRS 2012 report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an existing stored procedure that I modified to return one more column.  I need to get that new column into the existing SSRS report. The report is simple but I want to avoid recreating the whole report if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In DataSet properties, go to the "Query" tab. Press the "Refresh Fields" button, and click OK. Save the report. When you go to the "Fields" tab of DataSet properties, the new column should appear.

(This is for Visual Studio 2013. For other versions, the UI may be slightly different, but the basic approach still applies.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to edit the current report, most places I have worked have some type of file control like TFS. Another option is to download the rdl file off the server and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You have the dataset collection created for this , Edit that ( Ctrl + L ) add the new column name  >> Save and refresh